# Regex to match everything after certain character and until certain character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I have a string as follows:

```
[a]:A Text, [ab]:AB Text, [abc]:ABC Text, [ab-c]:AB-C Text
```

Everything in one line.. I want to get the text after `[a]:` all the way until `,`.

So I would like 4 matches for the above string... `A Text, AB Text, ABC Text and AB-C Text`

This gets me everything from the first colon to the last comma but it's still not what I am needing:

```
(?<=:)(.*)(?=,)
```

https://regex101.com/r/2we0sn/1

Comment: Use `(?<=:)([^,]+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that only gives the first match not all

Comment: You forgot to use the `g` flag at regex101.com

Comment: You are right! Thank you!... I was close

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Python `re`?

Comment: .NET @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Then you need `Regex.Matches(text, @":([^,]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)` (C#)